# Regex validation for time entries

Tags: java, regex, validation

I have a text box which accepts time in the format HH:mm and entries should only be in 24-hour format.For all invalid entries, a common message 'Invalid entry' should be displayed.

For eg:

```
19:61 //INVALID
12:00am //INVALID
12***M //INVALID

06:00 //VALID
22:00 //VALID
5:45 //VALID
```

The code required is in Java.
Not familiar with regex expressions...so need your ideas on it.Thx in advance! :)

```
String timeStr = getTimeBoxValue();
```

Comment: You need this regexp: `^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$`

Comment: @ash108: Can you explain how the expression works.Thx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [Link](http://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/10-java-regular-expression-examples-you-should-know/)
Which you can use.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Time24HoursValidator{

  private Pattern pattern;
  private Matcher matcher;

  private static final String TIME24HOURS_PATTERN = 
             "([01]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]";

  public Time24HoursValidator(){
      pattern = Pattern.compile(TIME24HOURS_PATTERN);
  }

  /**
   * Validate time in 24 hours format with regular expression
   * @param time time address for validation
   * @return true valid time fromat, false invalid time format
   */
  public boolean validate(final String time){

      matcher = pattern.matcher(time);
      return matcher.matches();

  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will checkout the link you provided! :)

Comment: @Vikky  i have to validate a similar format.In my case i have have to validate the time strictly for hh:mm. So for my case 01:30 should ve validated however 1:30 should not be. I am trying to get a hang of regex , but don't feel comfortable enough.Could you please give some input

Answer (score 2):

Too explain the regex in ash108:s comment:

```
^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):(([0-9])|([0-5][0-9]))$
```

`^` at the beginning of the string...

`([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])` ...there must be a number 0-9 OR a (number with first 0-1 and then 0-9) OR (a number with first 2 and then 0-3)

`:` then there must be a : sign

`([0-9])|([0-5][0-9])` then there must be a number 0-9 OR a (number with first 0-5 and then 0-9)

`$` and then there must be the end of the string

There is one thing a bit weird with this expression though, if you examine it. Look at the part after the : sign. It will allow a single digit 0-9. Hence a string as for example 12:5 would be valid. Imo this part should probably be removed resulting in:

```
^(([0-9])|([0-1][0-9])|([2][0-3])):([0-5][0-9])$
```

Now, the part after the : sign is forced to have two digits, while the part before the : sign can have either one or two digits.

Comment: How to add length to this regex? I know it's S{5} or w{5} but, not sure about that.